# Excel Javascript onChange Event Not Triggering When Data in Cell is Updated via a Data Validation Dropdown in Excel for Web

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, excel-addins

This is a problem that I have only just started having for about a month or so. I built a taskpane add-in for Excel using office.js for one of our departments at work. For almost 2 years it has been working perfectly fine in both the desktop Excel application for Mac and online via Excel for Web. About a month ago, we noticed that the add-in was no longer working properly when using Excel for Web. After investigating, I found that the problem was coming from cells whose data was being changed through a data validation dropdown box. These cells were no longer triggering the onChange event that was bound to the sheet. I must stress that this is only a problem with the web version of Excel, the data validation cells still trigger the onChange event when users are using the add-in through the desktop Excel application.

To try and weed out the problem, I created another simple taskpane add-in with a simple table and just a few lines of code. I used yo office to create a custom taskpane add-in for Excel using Javascript as the language. I did not change anything in the default HTML or CSS, I only updated the taskpane.js file. Below is the code that I used for this example:

```
Office.onReady((info) => {

    if (info.host === Office.HostType.Excel) {

        document.getElementById("sideload-msg").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("app-body").style.display = "flex";
        
        Excel.run(async (context) => {
            let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
            sheet.onChanged.add(onChange);
            await context.sync();
            console.log("On Change event is bound!")


        });

    };

});
    
async function onChange(event) {
    console.log("I have been TRIGGERED!!!!")
    let address = event.address;
    let value = event.details.value;

    if (event.source === Excel.EventSource.dataValidation) {
        console.log(`The value of ${address} was changed to ${value} by a dropdown selection.`);
    };
};
```

I then created a table in an empty Excel document with some basic info in it. Doesn't really matter what it is, but you can see the table I used in the gif below if you would like a reference. The only thing of note is that I made another table with some values in it that I used as the data validation for the last column of the table with the basic info in it. With the taskpane open, anytime I change a value in the table it should console log "I have been TRIGGERED!!!!". When using this on the Desktop Excel application, this works for all cells. However, once I upload the sheet to SharePoint and try to use it with Excel for Web, the function no longer triggers for data that is updated in the last column that has the data validation tied to it. Below is a gif demonstrating this issue:

[data-validation-cells-not-triggering-onChange-event-Excel-Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI2bA.gif)

I have tried searching for similar issues, but I have not found anything that matches what I am dealing with. I am thinking that this might be a bug with Excel for Web since I have only recently had these issues and up until a month ago everything was working perfectly fine on Excel for Web, but I wanted to see if anyone here had any suggestions for a fix/work around. The only thing I can think of would be to hard code the data validation into the js file rather than doing it through the data tab in Excel, but I hesitate to do that since the workbook that this is needed for has a ton of data validation in it, and it relies on the data validation being flexible so that way someone can go in and update the reference table and have it show up for all users. So if I can avoid going that route that would be preferable. Thanks!

Comment: This does look like a bug. If you don't get an answer here in the next couple of days, I recommend that you create and issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) repo.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @RickKirkham Thanks for your response! Yeah, I am planning on reporting it as a bug if there aren't any good work arounds or fixes suggested here within a week or two. Also thanks for the link to the office-js repo!

Comment: Just one thing, you mentioned uploading doc to SharePoint. Can you try creating tables/doc in Excel in Web and see if it still happens?

Comment: My thought/wonder if this is somehow related to the document being CREATED on Desktop then accessed in the Web, not that it should matter, would still be a bug, but could help drill down further.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Nice thought! I just tried making a new workbook from scratch in Excel for Web and I unfortunately got the same results. So it seems that the bug is not related to how the document was created. That was a good idea though that I hadn't thought of yet, so thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @MattCalvert what the heck, at this point, I'm just helping w/ debugging points for reporting to the github repo lol, but just curious, if you access the document created in the Web on desktop, does your code run?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers I just tried that out and everything seems to work as it should on Desktop even when the document was initially created on Excel for Web. So I guess that confirms that the bug is not related to how the document was created. I went ahead and reporting this to the GitHub repo, so hopefully they'll get this fixed